# Value not found for res1 in Scala worksheet?

Tags: scala

I'm an experienced C/C++/C# programmer starting up in Scala, using Eclipse based Scala IDE 4.3.0 final on Windows 8.1.  Usually I can reference a result variable in a further calculation in a Scala worksheet.  However, in the code below, the IDE keeps telling me that "not found: value res1".  Why can't I access *res1*?

Here's the code with the problem line commented out so you can see where *res1* appears:

```
object test1 {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")       //> Welcome to the Scala worksheet

  val r = 3                                       //> r  : Int = 3
  println(r)                                      //> 3
  r.toChar                                        //> res0: Char =
  val r2 = 3 * 6                                  //> r2  : Int = 18
  val r3 = 12 / 3                                 //> r3  : Int = 4
  r2 * r3                                         //> res1: Int = 72
  // val r5 = r2 + res1
}
```

Here's the code with the last line not commented out, that gives me the error:

```
object test1 {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")

  val r = 3
  println(r)
  r.toChar
  val r2 = 3 * 6
  val r3 = 12 / 3
  r2 * r3
  val r5 = r2 + res1
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to depend on a result environment created by the REPL instead of assigning it to a variable instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think res0, res1 is what you have seen in REPL.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop

When you write code with IDE, no res0 nor res1 be created in current environment.